# NextJS: pass data from custom server to nextjs middleware

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

For context, my application is using a [custom nextjs server](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server), and [nextjs middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) for handling authorization. Inside the middleware file, I'm attempting to access AWS Secrets Manager API to pull secrets required to validate the sessions on the incoming request.

Due to limitations with nextjs middleware, mainly the fact that it runs using edge runtime, I'm unable to access filesystem APIs (`fs`), which means the usual means of providing credentials to the AWS SDK within the middleware is not available (credential files, ini files). Additionally, for security reasons I'm not able to use environment variables to provide credentials such as `ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

My plan is to use [fromWebToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-credential-providers/Variable/fromWebToken/) credentials provider, which means I need to pass the `webIdentityToken` as a parameter. The value of this token is stored in a file within the pod, which is automatically mounted by k8s.

I wish to do the following:

1. In the nextjs custom server node request handler, read the contents of this file using `readFileSync`
2. Augment the `IncomingMessage` request object in some way to set custom data which will include the token value from Step 1, before invoking the `handle` method provided by nextjs itself
3. When nextjs middleware is called, read this custom data off the request in order to pass this downstream to the AWS SDK

I'm running into problems augmenting the node provided `IncomingMessage` and having that data be persisted through into the call to the middleware.

Things I've tried:

1. Extended the `parsedURL` object to include the custom data as the third option to the `handle` method:
   `await handle(request, response, { ...parsedUrl, customData });`
   When the middleware is invoked the `customData` property on ``` searchParams``NextRequest ``` object is not present.
2. Create my own custom class which extends `IncomingMessage` with `set` and `get` methods for this custom data. Then pass this via the `ServerOptions` argument for the `createServer` call. Next.js is doing some normalisation of the IncomingMessage internally, so by the time this comes to the middleware this data is gone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.